# How to allow a specific directory to be used with iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, permissions

There is a directory on my website that contains some PDF files that I want to show on a page, But unfortunately I can't because:

If I entered the src="https://www.mywebsite.com/files/file.pdf", The file is downloaded instead of viewing .

and if I entered src="https://www.mywebsite.com/files/", a message appears saying that this directory is forbidden and I have to change the file permissions.

If I entered src="https://www.mywebsite.com" it shows the login page.

- Is there is a way to make this directory available so that I can view the files ?
- Or what should the permissions be so that I could be able to view PDF files ?

Comment: already asked an our ago ! Topic flagged as duplicate

Answer (score 0):

** Try embed **

`<embed src="https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/cprogramming_tutorial.pdf" width="800px" height="2100px" />`